# Python - how to convert a json.loads variable to list and append

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Basically I need to get the json content of a file, replace a variable and then append it with a new dictionary. I've tried in every way and searched but I can't find a solution. *The first line exemplifies the data that comes from the .json file

```py
liststr = [{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Olá {user} :wave:\n\n Segue abaixo a listagem de colaboradores terceiro sob sua gestão e a data de expiração da conta. \n\nA data de expiração máxima para a conta é de 30 dias. Caso o período de renovação exceda esse limite, a data será fixada em D+30. "}}]
liststr = str(liststr)
liststr = liststr.replace("{user}", "Bruno")
listlist = json.loads(json.dumps(liststr))
print(listlist)
```

Even that part works fine. The issue is that as I said, I need to append with one more information, for example:

```py
liststr = [{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Olá {user} :wave:\n\n Segue abaixo a listagem de colaboradores terceiro sob sua gestão e a data de expiração da conta. \n\nA data de expiração máxima para a conta é de 30 dias. Caso o período de renovação exceda esse limite, a data será fixada em D+30. "}}]
liststr = str(liststr)
liststr = liststr.replace("{user}", "Bruno")
listlist = json.loads(json.dumps(liststr))
listlist.append({
        "user": "bruno"
    })
print(listlist)
```

I get the error message

> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

because it considers the json.loads variable to be str instead of list. I've tried converting it to a list but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You are working with a string, period. Don't work with strings. `json.loads(json.dumps(...))` does exactly nothing. You turn a value into JSON and then decode it again, leaving you with the original value. Which is a string.

Comment: They way to handle this is not with converting to and from strings with replacement. Better to identify the key(s) within the dictionaries that might potentially be modified. What are the rules here?

Comment: @deceze The data is coming from a file. The first line is just to exemplify the data that is coming from the file.

Comment: What data exactly is in the file…?! Certainly not a list that you're turning into a string…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def replace(v, needle, replacement):
    if isinstance(v, str):
        return v.replace(needle, replacement)
    if isinstance(v, list):
        return [replace(i, needle, replacement) for i in v]
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        return {k: replace(i, needle, replacement) for k, i in v.items()}
    return v

l = [{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Olá {user} :wave:\n\n Segue abaixo a listagem de colaboradores terceiro sob sua gestão e a data de expiração da conta. \n\nA data de expiração máxima para a conta é de 30 dias. Caso o período de renovação exceda esse limite, a data será fixada em D+30. "}}]
l = replace(l, '{user}', 'buno')
```

This is what you're trying to do. Recursively iterate over all values in the list of dicts, and replace the string "{user}" in any of them, all the while keeping everything as a list of dicts and not turning everything into a string.

Comment: This function solved the problem. The right thing was to do the hard work, that is, go through everything and do the replace at the right time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what the logic is here so making an assumption that any dictionary with a key of 'text' whose value is a string may need modification. If that is the case then:

```
list_ = [{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "Olá {user} :wave:\n\n Segue abaixo a listagem de colaboradores terceiro sob sua gestão e a data de expiração da conta. \n\nA data de expiração máxima para a conta é de 30 dias. Caso o período de renovação exceda esse limite, a data será fixada em D+30. "}}]

def process(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            process(v)
        else:
            if isinstance(v, str) and k == 'text':
                d['text'] = v.replace('{user}', 'Bruno')
                break

for d in list_:
    process(d)

print(list_)
```